# meaning of hiragana in a verse

Tags: words, hiragana, onomatopoeia, poetry

This sentence is from a poem:

トイレットペーパーしゅるる.

The katakanas mean "toilet paper". How about the hiraganas?

I thought it would be a verb because of the る-ending, but can't find a verb like this in the dictionary.

Comment: I had wrongly typed しゆるる instead of しゅるる. Following the suggestions below, I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「しゅるる」 is an onomatopoeia that describes, in this case, the sound made by the toilet paper rolling.

The variants include  「しゅるしゅる」、「シュルシュル」、「シュルル」, etc.

Onomatopoeias are an important part of our language and that is such an understatement.  Onomatopoeias rule.